# C++ What's wrong with my DFS code?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, depth-first-search

I have tried to code the DFS algorithm as given in CLRS. Here's the code below. When I run it I got an error as "Your program stopped unexpectedly." When I debugged the code I got this line in the call stack  "msvcrt!malloc()" and "operator new(unsigned int)". I'm using CodeBlocks. Where am I wrong?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<vector>
#include<list>
#include<utility>
#include<algorithm>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

struct prop
{
    int p;
    int value;
    int d;
    int f;
    string color;
};

vector<prop>v;

prop make_prop(int a,int b,int c,int d,string e)
{
    prop p = {a,b,c,d,e};
    return p;
}

class Dfs
{
public:
    int time;
    vector<list<int> >adj;
    Dfs(int nv)
    {
        v.resize(nv);
        adj.resize(nv);
        for(int i=0;i<nv;i++)
        {
            v[i].value = i;
            v[i].p = -1;
            v[i].color = "WHITE";
        }
    }
    void addinput()
    {
        adj[0].push_back(1);
        adj[0].push_back(2);
        adj[0].push_back(3);
        adj[1].push_back(0);
        adj[1].push_back(3);
        adj[2].push_back(0);
        adj[2].push_back(3);
        adj[3].push_back(0);
        adj[3].push_back(1);
        adj[3].push_back(2);
    }
    void dfs();
    void dfsvisit(prop);
};

void Dfs::dfs()
{
    time = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++)
    {
        if(v[i].color == "WHITE")
        {
            dfsvisit(v[i]);
        }
    }
}

void Dfs::dfsvisit(prop m)
{
    time++;
    m.d = time;
    m.color = "GRAY";
    int val = m.value;
    for(auto it = adj[val].begin();it != adj[val].end();it++)
    {
        if(v[*it].color == "WHITE")
        {
            v[*it].p = val;
            dfsvisit(v[*it]);
        }
    }
    m.color = "BLACK";
    cout<<m.value;
    time++;
    m.f = time;
}

int main()
{
    Dfs d(4);
    d.addinput();
    d.dfs();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One thing right away is that you don't check if any of the indices used in the `adj` vector are in bounds.  You also #included the wrong header for `std::string`.  The header is `<string>`, not `<cstring>`

Comment: I will never understand space-averse programming. Put spaces around your operators! It will be much easier for people to read your code. e.g. `for(auto it = adj[val].begin(); it != adj[val].end(); it++)`

Comment: Updated <cstring> to <string> and also added spaces.

Comment: @user3739818 Your `dfsvisit` function results in a stack overflow error, indicating that it just calls itself in an infinite recursion loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void Dfs::dfsvisit(prop m) // should be prop&
```

`dfsvisit(prop m)` will make a copy of the property while `dfsvisit(prop& m)` receives a reference, working directly on the property you passed to the function

Comment: Thanks alot! It's working. Can you please tell me why it should be prop &m ?

Answer (score 1):

the stack will overflow!
In function dfsvisit,you pass parameter by value,which will never change the actual parameter.You should pass parameter by reference.

```
void dfsvisit(prop& m);
```